# Andengine Troubles, Nothing showing on screen? SimpleBaseGameActivity

Tags: android, android-activity, andengine

I have this code:

```
public class GameActivity extends SimpleBaseGameActivity{

static final int CAMERA_WIDTH = 800;
static final int CAMERA_HEIGHT = 480;

public Font mFont;
public Camera mCamera;

public Scene mCurrentScene;
public static BaseActivity instance;


@Override
public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    instance = this;
    mCamera = new Camera(0,0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);
    return new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_FIXED, new RatioResolutionPolicy(CAMERA_WIDTH,  CAMERA_HEIGHT), mCamera);
}

@Override
protected void onCreateResources() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mFont = FontFactory.create(this.getFontManager(), this.getTextureManager(), 256, 256, Typeface.create(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD), 32);
    mFont.load();
}

@Override
protected Scene onCreateScene() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new FPSLogger());
    mCurrentScene = new Scene();
    mCurrentScene.setBackground(new Background(0.09804f, 0.7274f, 0.8f));


    return mCurrentScene;
}

}
```

My Whole goal is to just get something on the screen, just a simple bitmap. Ive followed a bunch of tutorials on andengine on youtube and google, but for some reason when i start the basegameactivity it doesnt display anything at all just a blank white screen. I also downloaded an example from github and copied and pasted the code and the example gave me the same thing just a blank white screen. Can anyone help me? Id appreciate it :]

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using GLES2 andengine branch and may be your phone is not supporting GLES2.

Comment: my s4 doesnt support gles2? o.0 ive seen people on youtube run this app on the emulator so i would think my s4 supports it

Comment: after playing with the code a bit i realize that none of the methods are getting called :/

Comment: You can use the older andengine version which supports GLES1 and then it should work for you..